# C: Part of the code doesn't execute under select()

Tags: c, select, timer

I have something like this:

```
#define QUIT_TIME 5
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        //... SOCKETS STUFF ....
    fdmax = parentfd;


    while (notdone) {

        //Set the timers
        waitd.tv_sec = 1;
        waitd.tv_usec = 0;

        FD_ZERO(&tempreadfds);
        FD_ZERO(&tempwritefds);

        FD_ZERO(&readfds);          /* initialize the read fd set */
        FD_ZERO(&writefds);         /* initialize the write fd set */

        FD_SET(parentfd, &readfds); /* add listener socket fd */
        FD_SET(0, &readfds);        /* add stdin fd (0) */

        tempreadfds = readfds; //make a copy
        tempwritefds = writefds; //make a copy

        if (select(fdmax+1, &tempreadfds, &tempwritefds, (fd_set*) 0, &waitd) < 0) {
            error("ERROR in select");
        }

        for(i = 1; i <= fdmax; i++) {

            if(FD_ISSET(i, &readfds)) {
                if(i == parentfd) {
                //This is a new connection
                childfd = accept(parentfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
                if (childfd < 0)
                    error("ERROR on accept");

                InitializeDataStructures(childfd);

                FD_SET(childfd, &readfds); //add to the master set
                if(childfd > fdmax)
                    fdmax = childfd;
            } else {
                //Existing connection
                if((nBytes = read(i, connections[i].buffer, MAXBUFFER)) <= 0) {
                    if(nBytes == 0) {
                        //Connection closed
                        printf("Socket %d hung up\n", read_write_loop);
                    } else {
                        error("\nReceive error\n");
                    }

                    FD_CLR(i, &readfds);
                } else {
                    //We have some data from the connection
                                            //... Manipulate the buffer
                    //Handle the message
                }
            }
            }

            if(FD_ISSET(i, &writefds)) {
                                .....
                FD_CLR(i, &writefds);
            }

            //Timer checking
            if(connections[i].active) {
                gettimeofday(&TimeNow, NULL);
                timeval_diff(&Interval, &TimeNow, &connections[i].TimeConnected);
                printf("*_*_*__*_*_*__*_*_*_*_* difference is %ld seconds, %ld microseconds\n",
                         Interval.tv_sec,
                         Interval.tv_usec
                        );
                if(Interval.tv_sec >= QUIT_TIME) {
                    printf("Timer elapsed!!\n");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /* clean up */
    printf("Terminating server.\n");
    close(parentfd);
    return 0;
}

void InitializeDataStructures(int i) {

    clients[i].active = YES;
    clients[i].fd = i;
    //Initialize other members of the structure
}

long long timeval_diff(struct timeval *difference, timeval *end_time, struct timeval *start_time) {
      struct timeval temp_diff;

      if(difference==NULL)
        difference=&temp_diff;

      difference->tv_sec =end_time->tv_sec -start_time->tv_sec ;
      difference->tv_usec=end_time->tv_usec-start_time->tv_usec;

      while(difference->tv_usec<0)
      {
        difference->tv_usec+=1000000;
        difference->tv_sec -=1;
      }

      return 1000000LL*difference->tv_sec + difference->tv_usec;

    }
```

I was expecting that the "Timer elapsed" line will be printed every at least once (The TimeConnected was initialized into one of the if conditions) during execution, but for some reason, it never prints out. I thought my while loop should keep printing it... Anyone know if I'm messing up somewhere?

EDIT:
Actually, I'm using the timer to disconnect the time after a timeout. I just observed that it prints "Timer elapsed" if another client connects to the server. I did pass the final parameter to select but am not sure why it is not having any effect.

Thanks to bdk!! If you're interested in knowing the "silly" bug I had in this code, read the discussion below in detail... It was an obvious mistake that I overlooked... all because of one sentence in the tutorials: "select modifies your original descriptors".

**List of changes:**

- Notice that a set of FD_ZERO statements were wrongly placed inside the while loop
- FD_ISSET was being passed readfds and writefds instead of tempreadfds and tempwritefds...

**WORKING CODE:**

```
#define QUIT_TIME 5
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        //... SOCKETS STUFF ....
    fdmax = parentfd;


    FD_ZERO(&readfds);          /* initialize the read fd set */
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);         /* initialize the write fd set */

    while (notdone) {

        //Set the timers
        waitd.tv_sec = 1;
        waitd.tv_usec = 0;

        FD_ZERO(&tempreadfds);
        FD_ZERO(&tempwritefds);


        FD_SET(parentfd, &readfds); /* add listener socket fd */
        FD_SET(0, &readfds);        /* add stdin fd (0) */

        tempreadfds = readfds; //make a copy
        tempwritefds = writefds; //make a copy

        if (select(fdmax+1, &tempreadfds, &tempwritefds, (fd_set*) 0, &waitd) < 0) {
            error("ERROR in select");
        }

        for(i = 1; i <= fdmax; i++) {

            if(FD_ISSET(i, &tempreadfds)) {
                if(i == parentfd) {
                //This is a new connection
                childfd = accept(parentfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
                if (childfd < 0)
                    error("ERROR on accept");

                InitializeDataStructures(childfd);

                FD_SET(childfd, &readfds); //add to the master set
                if(childfd > fdmax)
                    fdmax = childfd;
            } else {
                //Existing connection
                if((nBytes = read(i, connections[i].buffer, MAXBUFFER)) <= 0) {
                    if(nBytes == 0) {
                        //Connection closed
                        printf("Socket %d hung up\n", read_write_loop);
                    } else {
                        error("\nReceive error\n");
                    }

                    FD_CLR(i, &readfds);
                } else {
                    //We have some data from the connection
                                            //... Manipulate the buffer
                    //Handle the message
                }
            }
            }

            if(FD_ISSET(i, &tempwritefds)) {
                                .....
                FD_CLR(i, &writefds);
            }

            //Timer checking
            if(connections[i].active) {
                gettimeofday(&TimeNow, NULL);
                timeval_diff(&Interval, &TimeNow, &connections[i].TimeConnected);
                printf("*_*_*__*_*_*__*_*_*_*_* difference is %ld seconds, %ld microseconds\n",
                         Interval.tv_sec,
                         Interval.tv_usec
                        );
                if(Interval.tv_sec >= QUIT_TIME) {
                    printf("Timer elapsed!!\n");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /* clean up */
    printf("Terminating server.\n");
    close(parentfd);
    return 0;
}

void InitializeDataStructures(int i) {

    clients[i].active = YES;
    clients[i].fd = i;
    //Initialize other members of the structure
}

long long timeval_diff(struct timeval *difference, timeval *end_time, struct timeval *start_time) {
      struct timeval temp_diff;

      if(difference==NULL)
        difference=&temp_diff;

      difference->tv_sec =end_time->tv_sec -start_time->tv_sec ;
      difference->tv_usec=end_time->tv_usec-start_time->tv_usec;

      while(difference->tv_usec<0)
      {
        difference->tv_usec+=1000000;
        difference->tv_sec -=1;
      }

      return 1000000LL*difference->tv_sec + difference->tv_usec;

    }
```

Comment: Oh I was typing the code here... Must have been a typo... Fixing it now...

Comment: Why don't you copy-paste the code, so we can see what it actually is and can catch if you've made any silly typos?

Comment: Ok sorry... I updated the code with a copy-paste version...

Comment: If that's your copy-pasted version, then the problem is that you're using defining `THRESHOLD` but comparing against `QUIT_TIME`.

Comment: Are you seeing the output of the `printf` with all the asterisks and underscores in it? Because if not, then the problem is either that `connection[i].active` is never true, or `printf`'s output is going somewhere that you don't see it.

Comment: @Anon: Believe me.. that is the copy-paste... except that I forgot to put the define line... There are a bunch of constants and header files which is the reason I am not copy-pasting my entire file...

@caf: Yes... it is printing the asterisks and underscores (but only once.. not periodically)... The problem is coming only with the inner condition...

Comment: Actually, I'm using the timer to disconnect the time after a timeout. I just observed that it prints "Timer elapsed" if another client connects to the server...

Comment: You don't use the value returned by timeval_diff(); this may not matter, but perhaps the function should be defined to return 'long long' since you use a 'long long' constant in the calculation of the return value.

Comment: Thanks.. Yeah that should've been long long but now the problem seems to be something very different... I am seeing that select times out exactly once and I am not understanding where it is blocking.. time for the debugger I guess...

Comment: You also do not show the code that initializes connections[i].TimeConnected.  (Is there any significance to the placement of the double-underscores in the line of stars and underscores?)  Have you tried printing out the difference in the timeval_diff() function?  Also, since connections[i].fd = i, you are not really storing anything you don't already know.  However, none of this really explains what is going wrong.

Comment: When the InitializeDataStructures is called for the first time, I record the present time: gettimeofday(&connections[i].TimeConnected, NULL); and that's all. I don't touch this thereafter. Regarding the double-scores, I was just going crazy debugging the code for the last one hour :) I ran it through the debugger... after printing once, it seems to block near the accept call inside the for loop... and I have no clue why that is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your select loop parameters, they look fishy to me. Mainly in that you are calling select on tempreadfd and tempwritefd, but then when you call FD_ISSET, you pass it readfd and writefd. before calling select, you are using FD_SET to set all the fd's you are interested in. Since these variables aren't being sent to select, the fds that haven't triggered aren't getting masked. Therefore, you are getting 'activity' detected on all your descriptors. There really isn't any activity on that accept descriptor, so it blocks until a new client connects.

Thats my guess at least.

Comment: The reason I am passing a copy of the readfds and writefds is because select ends up modifying the original descriptors. At least, that is what is written in the man page and the Unix Network programming book by Stevens...

Comment: Yes, Its fine to pass the copy into select, but then pass the same copy into FD_ISSET

Comment: No but wait... I cannot pass those to FD_ISSET because select destroys those things which is the reason I am making a copy in the first place... :)

Comment: You need to have at least one copy of your FD's that you are willing to leet get destroyed. You need to pass that copy to both select and FD_ISSET. Otherwise, when select modify's your FD's to show which ones have activity, you won't see that activity in FD_ISSET, because you will be looking at a different set.

Comment: Note that select doesn't just randomly "destroy" your fd sets, it reuses them to store its results in (puts 1's in the fd's that have activity, 0's in the others). Thats why you need the 'copy' for multiple calls to select. Just use tempreadfd/tempwritefd in your FD_ISSET, and it should work. Note that you're thread solution below fixes the timeout issue, but your current usage of select will exhibit other bugs as you move forward, for example it will be calling 'read' on every file descriptor in your set, not just the ones that have activity.

Comment: Yeah! I guess what you say makes sense now... But now, the code stopped working completely. I mean, the connection gets established but the client does not send any data to the server... I guess maybe that is because, even if I'm setting readfds, I am still zeroing it out when it enters the while loop....

Comment: Thats because you have a different bug that was being masked by the first one :). Every time you call select, you are zeroing out (FD_ZERO) both the tempreadfd and readfd. You are only storing your extra client fd's in the readfdset, so when you FD_ZERO them, you are losing all record of them existing. The only reason this was working before was because your loop was erroneiously calling read on all the fds regardless of what select was telling it.

Comment: Yeah... moving FD_ZERO(&readfds) and FD_ZERO(&writefds) to outside the for loop makes it work again... I have no idea what other bugs I introduced with my bad paradigm... Will get back in a few minutes..

Comment: Wow... That solved all the problems! The timer works as well in its original form... I seriously cannot thank you enough... You ended up not only correcting the code, but also made me realize the idiotic bug that I introduced... Thank you once again...!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code right, you enter your while loop, then check to see if the descriptor is in the read set.  If it is, then you go to the accept() portion of your if statement.  If it is not, then you enter the else portion, where you immediately block on a read.  If the socket is active, bot there is no data available, you will block there until data becomes available.  It will not drop through to the section where it even checks the timer until it gets either a successful read or an error on the input.

You should only enter the code where you check the sockets if select returns a value greater than zero, then you should check to see if the socket is in the read set before you attempt to read from it.

Normally you build one fdset to check for the sockets you're accepting connections on, and another for the ones you've accepted and are actually reading data on.  I suppose you can do it the way you've presented, but I'd suggest you switch from read() to recv() and use the MSG_PEEK flag.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very code specific problem but who knows... maybe it would be of some help to others.. I ended up using a thread to solve the problem (I know... not the best but I'm just going nuts trying to debug this...). Thanks to everyone who had the patience to help me out...

In the above code, instead of testing the timer inside the while loop of main(), I modified it as follows:

```
if(ThreadSpawned == 0) {
                pthread_create(&thread, NULL, cleanup, (void *) &fdmax);
                ThreadSpawned = 1;
            }
```

And then the cleanup function is as follows:

```
void *cleanup(void *arg) {
    //Timer checking
    int i, *fdmax;
    fdmax = (int *) arg;

    while(1) {
        for(i = 1; i <= *fdmax; i++) {
            if(connections[i].active == 1) {
                gettimeofday(&TimeNow, NULL);
                timeval_diff(&Interval, &TimeNow, &clients[i].TimeConnected);
                printf("*_*_*__*_*_*__*_*_*_*_* difference is %ld seconds, %ld microseconds\n",
                        Interval.tv_sec,
                        Interval.tv_usec
                );
                fflush(stdout);
                if((int) Interval.tv_sec >= QUIT_TIME) {
                    printf("Timer elapsed!!\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
            }
        }
        sleep(20);
    }
}
```

Any cleaner solutions are most welcome. Perhaps, the reason suggested by bdk in one of his answers is the reason the program is blocking at accept but then, if it blocks there, I'll have no way of calculating a timeout... So I ended up using a thread to do this task...